# How to find the position of the elements in an array by Python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have following array:

```
scores=[2.619,3.3, 9.67, 0.1, 6.7,3.2]
```

And I wish to retrieve the elements which more than 5 by following code:

```
min_score_thresh=5
Result=scores[scores>min_score_thresh]
```

Hence this will result me result:

```
[9.67, 6.7]
```

Now i wish to get the positions of this two element which is my expected answer will be store in variable x:

x = [2,4]

Please share me ideas, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scores = [2.619, 3.3, 9.67, 0.1, 6.7, 3.2]

min_score_thresh = 5

# score is 5 or higher
result = []

# position in 'scores' list
indx = []

for i, item in enumerate(scores):
    if item > min_score_thresh:
        result.append(item)
        indx.append(i)

x = indx

print(result)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `numpy.where` for a vectorised solution:

```
import numpy as np

scores = np.array([2.619,3.3, 9.67, 0.1, 6.7,3.2])
min_score_thresh = 5

res = np.where(scores>min_score_thresh)[0]

print(res)

[2 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

Getting the indices (or values) via list comprehension is easy:

```
In [33]: [i for i,v in enumerate(scores) if v>5]
Out[33]: [2, 4]
```

We can get both, as a list of tuples with:

```
In [34]: [(i,v) for i,v in enumerate(scores) if v>5]
Out[34]: [(2, 9.67), (4, 6.7)]
```

Then we can use a `zip*` idiom to 'transpose' this list:

```
In [35]: list(zip(*_))
Out[35]: [(2, 4), (9.67, 6.7)]
```

Or wrapping that all in one expression with unpacking:

```
In [36]: v,x = tuple(zip(*((i,v) for i,v in enumerate(scores) if v>5)))
In [37]: v
Out[37]: (2, 4)
In [38]: x
Out[38]: (9.67, 6.7)
```

At a first glance getting several lists from a list comprehension is tricky, but this zip* transposition takes care of that.

Answer (score 2):

Using `numpy`:

```
x = np.flatnonzero(np.greater(scores, min_score_thresh)).tolist()
```

NOTE: `.tolist()` is not necessary if you can live with `numpy.ndarray`s.

Answer (score 1):

```
def find_scores(a_list, min):
    filters = list(filter( lambda x: x[1]> min, [(i[0],i[1]) for i in enumerate(a_list) ]))
    return [i[0] for i in filters]
```

Answer (score 1):

simple oneliners

```
scores = [2.619, 3.3, 9.67, 0.1, 6.7, 3.2]
min_score_thresh = 5

result = [scr for scr in scores if scr > min_score_thresh]
index_ = [scores.index(x) for x in result]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Dictionary,

```
scores = [2.619,3.3, 9.67, 0.1, 6.7,3.2]
min_score_thresh = 5


index_dict = {}
 
for index, word in enumerate(scores):
    if word > min_score_thresh :
        index_dict.setdefault(word, index)
 

print(*index_dict.values())
```

gives

```
2 4

[Program finished]
```